# adding numbers in texboxes

Tags: addition

I have 7 text boxes. I want to add the value of 7 and insert the total in to another textbox. How can i achieve that with out postback. I have also tried to update panel but it is not working. my code is as follows. ANy suggestions in this regards would be much appreciable

If Page.IsPostBack Then

```
        Dim A1 As Double
        A1 = A_SAtxt.Text
        Dim A2 As Double
        A2 = A_SStxt.Text
        Dim A3 As Double
        A3 = A_RAtxt.Text
        Dim A4 As Double
        A4 = A_CAtxt.Text
        Dim A5 As Double
        A5 = A_OItxt.Text
        Dim A6 As Double
        A6 = A_ICtxt.Text
        Dim A7 As Double
        A7 = A_Otxt.Text


        Dim ATotal = A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7
```

End If

I working in asp.net with VB. textbox code in asp.net is as follows

```
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-        align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top" class="style7" width = "400px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label154" runat="server" Text="Savings account $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_SAtxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label155" runat="server" Text="Stock and securities $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_SStxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label156" runat="server" Text="Retirement accounts $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_RAtxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label157" runat="server" Text="Checking account $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_CAtxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label158" runat="server" Text="Other investments $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_OItxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label159" runat="server" Text="Insurace cash-in-value $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_ICtxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label160" runat="server" Text="Other $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_Otxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label188" runat="server" Text="specify:" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_OStxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" Width="250px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: right; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label161" runat="server" Text="Total assets $"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="style7" 
                                    style="border:1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #F0F0F0;" 
                                    valign="top">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="A_TAtxt" runat="server" CssClass="DrpItems10" 
                                        style="text-align: left" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                         </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have even tried doing this but it doesn't seems to work

```
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append(" $(document).ready(function() {")
        sb.Append(" var numberInput = $('#A_SAtxt, #A_SStxt, #A_RAtxt, #A_CAtxt,                 

                #A_OItxt, #A_ICtxt, #A_Otxt');")
        sb.Append("  numberInput.on('change', function() {")
        sb.Append(" var total = 0;")
        sb.Append("else{")
        sb.Append(" numberInput.each(function() {")
        sb.Append("  if ($(this).val() !== '') {")
        sb.Append("  total += parseFloat($(this).val());")
        sb.Append(" }")
        sb.Append(" });")
        sb.Append(" $('#A_TAtxt').val(total);")
        sb.Append("  });")
        sb.Append(" });​")

        sb.Append("}};</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "function", sb.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or javascript to calculate the sum of the 7 input boxes and insert the value into another input on the client side.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var total = 0;

$('#A_SAtxt, #A_SStxt, #A_RAtxt, #A_CAtxt, #A_OItxt, #A_ICtxt, #A_Otxt').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
});

$('#A_TAtxt').val(total);
```

**DEMO**

Here is an example of this code in action: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AWGsw/2/

****EDIT 1****

To call this function on page load and to immediately add values on input blur, do the following:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var numberInput = $('#A_SAtxt, #A_SStxt, #A_RAtxt, #A_CAtxt, #A_OItxt, #A_ICtxt, #A_Otxt');

    numberInput.on('change', function() {
        var total = 0;

        numberInput.each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });

        $('#A_TAtxt').val(total);
    });

});
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/AWGsw/4/

Comment: Thank you for your response. My question is how do you call this function on page load. It should immediately add values as soon as the cursor leaves the text box after entering the value.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I just want to know that how will you call this java script function in page load VB.net code. I have tried using the following but it doesn't seem to work ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "();", True)

Comment: I'm not a vb.net programmer. So I don't know. But what I imagine you would do is put this code into a .js file and include it in the head or however you include a javascript file in vb.net. Make sure you include jQuery before you include this code. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js